# .Net Maui missing DPad for android TV

Tags: maui, .net-maui.shell

I'm trying to publish an application on Android TV, but my app was rejected because it doesn't have D-Pad functionality support.

Now, how I suppose to give to the user the ability to navigate between my app elements including the FlyoutMenu Shell?

Obviously, there is no such thing as nextFocusDown, nextFocusUP, nextFocusLeft, or nextFocusRight in .NET Maui XAML.

And there is no way to open the FlyoutMenu without a Touch Screen or a mouse (On Windows)

I even tried to search for a relative solution on Xamarin Forms since it is based on Xamarin when it comes to Android and IOS, but with results at all.

I also raised a new issue on [.NET Maui issues](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/12318)

Does anyone have a suggestion or a way/hack to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the comments about the MAUI on the Android TV. You can refer to the [Xaml for MAUI tvOS and Android TV](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/2974). The member of the MAUI team told that have no current plans to support TV platforms. So, the method `nextFocusDown、nextFocusUP、nextFocusLeft` can not be found in MAUI.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I know so I ended up adding a new layout with no menu, and that works with the controller the same as the normal Tap stop function on Windows (which is still not included in MAUI) but I mean the default controls' order.

I also converted the menu to a regular content page with buttons that basically used to navigate to the rest of the app's pages

Comment: Great! It sounds like you have finished most of the works, If you have the solution you can post it as an answer for other people to refer to.